# Whole page table with tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying to make a full page table using tabularx. As far as I can understand, the second parameter specifies the entire size and the "X" columns self-stretch to fill it up. What I run into is a table that is split at the end of the page and I cannot seem to make it shift to the right. What am I doing wrong here? I should also mentioned I've tried experimeting with *textheight* and *textwidth* but could not figure out how to force the width.

Example code below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \begin{landscape}

   \begin{tabularx}{290mm}{|c|c|c|X|}
   \hline
   Lorem & Lorem & Lorem & \lipsum[1] \\
   \hline
   \end{tabularx}

  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you have some issues, first off the `290mm` should really be `\linewidth` or `\textwidth`. Second, you should put a `\noindent` in front of the tabular. And finally, not so much of an issue, remove the page number.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \begin{landscape}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|c|X|}
      \hline
      Lorem & Lorem & Lorem & \lipsum[1] \\
      \hline
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

To address the comment, it's not how I read it, but if that is in fact the case, the following can be used (Adjusted after egreg's comment):

```
\centering\makebox[0pt][c]{%
  \hskip-\footskip
  \begin{tabularx}{\paperheight}{|c|c|c|X|}
    \hline
    Lorem & Lorem & Lorem & \lipsum[1] \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}%
  \hskip\headheight
}
```

Comment: I think the original question specifically says that \linewidth is not an option as it keeps the table within the margins. I think the question is to get the table from edge to edge of the page ignoring margins.

Comment: @ArTourter: That's not how I read it, but I added an alternative for that case.

Comment: I'd prefer `\centering\makebox[0pt][c]{...}` instead of the foreign command `\centerline`.

Comment: @egreg: Not that I disagree, but do you have any specific reason for that preference?

Comment: @RoelofSpijker It's an unsupported command and behaves in a way that users might find surprising (for example it doesn't force horizontal mode).

Comment: @egreg: I'll change the code. I am still curious about this though. From what I understand, `\centering` places it's argument in a `\hbox to\hsize` with `\hss` on either side to center it. Would that not force it to be in restricted horizontal mode?

Comment: @RoelofSpijker No, `\hbox` doesn't force horizontal mode.

Answer (score 9):

You have a paragraph indent to the left of the table and the specified width is considerably more than the horizontal size, because of the margins. try

```
  \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{|c|c|c|X|}
```

Comment: Thank you - very helpful but part of the solution.